# Multiple Jibri recording available same time

Tags: pulseaudio, jitsi

I have installed jitsi with docker containers of web, prosodyctl, jvb, jicofo, etherpad, jigasi. I have successfully record one session in same time. When we start record another session it given error jibri is busy, so can't start recording.

Are you have best solution for this task?

I have seen an article we can use pulseaudio dockerized jibri. Is it best solution for this? And How to setup it?

I need to start multiple recordings in same time.

Answer (score 1):

A Jibri instance can only record one conference session. You should create Jibri instances(each as Docker container or separate virtual/dedicated server) as many as you want to record conference room session recording at the same time.
In other words if you need x rooms to record at the same time, you need x Jibri instances.
Pulse audio is alternative and new solution for audio instead of alsa while recording.